# Rich text editor for front-end use in MODX Revolution 2.2.5pl

Tags: tinymce, modx, modx-revolution

I am creating a site where a user should be able to make html-content the same way as a manager can do it in backend.

It would be nice if the user also can upload pictures the same way as backend.

Is there a way to use the TinyMCE package that is installed for backend?

MODX version: Revolution 2.2.5pl

Answer (score 0):

no such extra that I am aware of, however - you are going to want to install and configure a separate instance of tinymce rather than try to force the installation used for the manager to behave as you want it to.

short thread here:
http://forums.modx.com/thread/?thread=46174&page=1